# A free or affordable option to profile Xamarin.Forms apps

Tags: android, ios, c#, profiling

I want to profile memory usage and performance on my Xamarin.Forms iOS and Android apps.

- The Xamarin Profiler is only available with a Visual Service Enterprise account, which is prohibitively expensive (several thousand dollars a year).
- I could compile to UWP and use JetBrains' dotTrace and dotMemory, but:
  a) that's not a real world scenario, there might be memory issues etc specific to iOS / Android implementations of Xamarin, and
  b) compiling to UWP in and of itself is a lot of work
- I can use the native Android / Apple profiling tools for Android Studio / XCode but they do not know about .NET objects - so finding the specific problem using these tools is a lot harder.

Is there a free or affordable option to profile Xamarin.Forms apps?

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm in the exact same boat right now, previously used xamarin profiler without realizing they require enterprise. 

Comment: Nope. FYI Xamarin Forms is going out of support in November 2023, so I wouldn't expect to get this for Xamarin. I'm not sure what the profiling situation will be for MAUI.